# Strtotime function not working for Martin Luther King Day

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm trying to create a function that returns all the federal holidays for a given year in php, but I'm having trouble getting a correct answer with the Marting Luther King Holiday. I'm caluculating the date as follows:

```
date('m/d/Y', strtotime("third monday January 2018"))
```

but I the function returns 01/22/2018 instead of the correct 01/15/2018. The same function with 2019 returns the correct date 01/21/2019. Any idea of how I could fix this?

Comment: `echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime("third monday of January 2018"));` gives `01/15/2018` - missing `of`.

Comment: Thanks, the missing "of" was indeed causing the problem